# What are the 'levels' of matches in Triple Town?

Tags: triple-town

I'm playing Triple Town on Android, and have never managed to match 3 on a mansion as yet.  So I was wondering how many levels I'm missing.  ;)

What I've seen:

**Rock starter:**

- Small rock (unmatched diamond)
- Large rock
- Treasure chest

**Bear starter:**

- Bear
- Gravestone
- Chapel
- Cathedral
- Treasure chest

**Grass starter:**

- Grass
- Bush
- Tree
- Barn
- House
- Mansion

Does the grass series eventually hit treasure chest as well?  Or are there extra levels I haven't managed to achieve so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always see what the next level of an item is by holding your finger above it (on the iOS version), you'll see it above the play field in the form of `item`+`item`+`item`=`match`.

Three mansions turn into a castle, three castles turn into sky castles. You can see two Sky Castles in this screen shot on the fourth row:

[image: Triple Town Screen Shot]

After you have four sky castles (exception from the previous "triple" pattern) it makes a bigger one, a floating Triple Castle, and that is the final level.